# How do I write vba filter with wildcard

Tags: ms-access, vba

can't work out where the quotes go in a filter string with wildcard

I'm trying to create a filter for a split form.

This works perfectly if I type in an exact match but I want to search for records containing the string.

Know I need to use * at start and end but can't get the '" right so it won't work

```
Private Sub SearchTxt_AfterUpdate()

If Not IsNull(Me.SearchTxt) Then
    Me.Filter like "ProductName = '" & Me.SearchTxt & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

trying to find Dish from dis or ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use wildcards to filter records try below:

```
Private Sub SearchTxt_AfterUpdate()

  If Not IsNull(Me.SearchTxt) Then
    Me.Filter = "ProductName like '*" & Me.SearchTxt & "*'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Those '""things do my head in. Thanks!